# Meaning of Javascript statements generated by Adobe Flash Pro CC

Tags: javascript, html, flash, html5-canvas, flash-cs5

When I draw a line on a HTML5 canvas with Flash Pro CC, it generates a statement like this:

```
// Layer 7
this.shape_2 = new cjs.Shape();
this.shape_2.graphics.f().s("#0033CC").ss(15,1,1).p("AjbAFIG3gJ");
this.shape_2.setTransform(647,302.5);
```

I am having trouble finding any documentation explaining what this means and how the statement would translate into a line. I am particularly mystified by the property `.p("AjbAFIG3gJ")` which I suspect holds the coordinates. Might a kind soul shed light on all this?

Comment: Try toggling the "uncompacted instructions" in the publish settings. It should output something a bit more human readable. http://blog.gskinner.com/archives/2015/04/introduction-to-the-flash-cc-html5-canvas-document.html

Comment: Thanks - it worked. The output is now easily readable by a human!